# How to enforce coding style conventions in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

I'm currently using Visual Studio Community for Mac 7.7.3 (build 43).

I'd like to enforce coding style conventions. I can't understand which is the most widely adopted tool to do it. StyleCop? FXCop? Microsoft Code Analysis? Any of them is the one that performs live code analysis in Visual Studio Community? Do I have to prefer an extension or a NuGet package?

I've read some books on C# but none of them covered tooling. Any advice?

Thanks,
Adriano

Comment: VS has good .editorconfig support these days, and it supports some quite specific details on style. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017

Comment: [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) got popular in recent days. Can be configured to run as part of the build.

Comment: I'd like to mention ReSharper. Otherwise, I would go for StyleCop.

Answer (score 1):

At my current place we use FxCop and StyleCop, enforced in the solution and build servers.  Both are free and are well integrated into the IDE.

We do have Resharper, but performance is so poor on large projects, that most devs have turned it off.  Also, it's a paid-for product, so not all developers have licences.

I would recommend not modifying the auto-format style, as most places I've worked at, use the defaults, so you might get into 'bad' habits that don't translate anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Most developers i know use Resharper. 
Stylecop is good, but it's too hard to make same rules in Stylecop and Resharper